# use/install of sp.js to call SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail

Tags: javascript

I believe the SharePoint server I am using has sp.js installed on it, as we can use `_spPageContextInfo`, but I cannot use the resource `SP.Utilites.Utility.SendEmail`.  I.E I am getting an error, stating this:

> System.NullReferenceException

Any thoughts?

Comment: Whoops!  Forgot to add that on the other server, I get an item that the resource cannot be found, even though it seems that sp.js is installed as well.  That's actually the bigger problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your site has MDS enabled. In such cased you should explicitly request the js files from the server using below code

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail', sendEmail);

function sendEmail(){
  //Your code goes here 
}
```

Comment: Hasim I tried my code, later in the day, and it appears to have worked, actually.  Thank you for the help, though.